# How to filter model choice field options based on user in django?

Tags: python, django, forms

Here is my form:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    Recipebase_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Recipebase.objects.filter(user = self.user))
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    instructions = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I want to filter model choice field based on user as you can see from the filter. But it gives the following error:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `self.` would work only for objects created from a class. In this case you are not creating one, so it would not work as you would expect.

Instead, you need to override the queryset in the `__init__` like this:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.Form):
    Recipebase_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Recipebase.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user') #Throws an error if user is not present
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Recipebase.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['Recipebase_id'].queryset = qs
```

Another way to achieve the same is to make `user` a required argument in the form

```
class RecipeForm(forms.Form):
    Recipebase_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Recipebase.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Recipebase.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['Recipebase_id'].queryset = qs
```

And the view code would look like this:

```
form = RecipeForm(request.POST, user=request.user) #user would be passed in as a kwarg to the form class.
```

Comment: it now throws exception for 'user' in the line: user = kwargs.pop('user')  :(

Comment: what is the exception ? It means you are not sending the `user` as a parameter when instantiating the form

Comment: Note that I removed the `None` fallback in the `pop` method. This is to make sure that you are sending the `user` as an argument. If not, it will throw an error

Comment: thats the whole problem, I dont really know where to get the user parameter from. I want to get it from the user who is signed in so when calling the form in views.py, I wrote:

form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.user)

Comment: You are missing the key.. Try this: `form = RecipeForm(request.POST, user=request.user)`

Comment: I tried, it throws exception for  user = kwargs.pop('user')  for: 'user' is a keyerror. I think it doesnt really recognize the word 'user'.

Comment: My guess is, something else is going on. I just edited the answer to make `user` a required argument to the `__init__` if this still does not work, something is wrong in your view. You might want to revisit how you are initializing this form object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103210/discussion-between-elisha512-and-karthikr).

Comment: Now it is throwing this: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: I see, I was inserting user=request.user in wrong place in the view. It works now . Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I searched for a while to figure this out. Your answer was clear and worked like a charm. I thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code starting at "Recipebase_id" at the indentation level you have it causes python to execute it at the time the file is parsed/imported.  Self is passed into a method when the class is instantiated and the instance method is called, so at parse time self does not exist.

It's unclear to me if you want the Recipebase_id, title and instructions set in the **init** method.  If you do, indent them to the same level as the lines above it.  If not, then you'll need to get the value of user from somewhere other than self.